# Clear/Deselect ComboBox control(s) within GroupBox control

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, combobox

## My problem:

I have a function to clear text boxes and combo boxes (`DropDownList`) within group boxes. Though the text boxes are clearing I cannot clear the combo boxes.

## My code:

```
Public Sub ClearGroupControls()
    For Each groupboxControl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf groupboxControl Is GroupBox Then
            For Each control As Control In groupboxControl.Controls
                ' Clear controls
                If TypeOf control Is TextBox Then
                    control.Text = ""
                ElseIf TypeOf control Is ComboBox Then
                    'control.Text = String.Empty
                    'control.SelectedIndex = -1
                    control.Text = ""
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Note: `.SelectedIndex = -1` produces the error:

> SelectedIndex is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.Control

...which seems inconsistent considering control.Text works when control is a TextBox.

Comment: What is the DropDownStyle of these combos?

Comment: @Steve `DropDownList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping over the collection of controls returns a generic control that has no SelectedIndex property.
You need to cast it to the appropriate type

```
Public Sub ClearGroupControls()
    For Each groupboxControl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)()
        For Each control As Control In groupboxControl.Controls
            ' Clear controls
            If TypeOf control Is TextBox Then
                control.Text = ""
            ElseIf TypeOf control Is ComboBox Then
                Dim cbo = DirectCast(control, ComboBox)
                cbo.SelectedIndex = -1
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Notice that in the outer loop you could use the IEnumerable extension to require just the controls of type GroupBox returned by the enumerator in the Controls collection of the Form.

You could change the inner loop to two loops to leverage the OfType extension but this should be measured if it really gives better performance (It largely depends on the number of controls present in your group boxes)

```
Public Sub ClearGroupControls()
    For Each groupboxControl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)()
        For Each txt In groupboxControl.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
            txt.Text = ""
        Next
        For Each cbo In groupboxControl.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()
           cbo.SelectedIndex = -1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It works but I'm not digesting what it is you're suggesting I can achieve with IEnumerable. I've researched the [official overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and a ["simplified" (as in, not at all) overview](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/ienumble.htm) but to no avail. Ultimately, are you saying it would replace the inner loop and furthermore, would you be patient/kind enough to direct me as to how?

Comment: Well I have no authority to explain better than the two links posted but think the `OfType` extensions like a filter applied to the Controls sequence that allows only the objects of the type indicated in the parenthesys to reach your `groupboxControl`  variable. In this way you could avoid the cast. The control variable groupboxControl is no more a generic control but a specific GroupBox control with its specific property

Comment: In the inner loop you need to check two different types of controls so it is not possible to have one loop OfType(????). You could code two loops, one for the TextBoxes and one for the ComboBoxes but I think that you gain nothing. So the route is to have a generic control and after the Is return true cast it to the ComboBox

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down. I ended up using a recursive method that relies on `TryCast()` and allows the parent to be specified as a parameter (and incidentally, allows `.SelectedIndex = -1`). [Working code](http://pastebin.com/wxSFNYeD) via PasteBin.